# Django file now showing in the template

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-templates, django-views

My file is being uploaded in the correct path but I have an issues with it:

- Whenever I refresh my HTML page the file gets uploaded again and again. How do I solve this? Also
  Please help me with the code or suggest me.

Thanks in advance:)

My views.py

```
def about_experiment(request, ex_link_name):
  researcher = None
  study = None
  posts = None
  exp = get_object_or_404(Experiment,link_name = ex_link_name)
  high_scores = ScoreItem.objects.filter(experiment=exp,active=True)
  context = {
    'request': request,
    'exp':exp,
    'high_scores': high_scores,
    'awards':AwardItem.objects.filter(experiment=exp,visible=True),
  }

  if exp.about_file:
    context['about_file'] = settings.EXPERIMENT_DIRS+exp.about_file.get_include_path()
    return render(request, 'about_experiment.html', context)

  if request.method == 'POST':
        form = AboutHelp(request.POST, request.FILES)
        posts = Help.objects.filter().order_by('-date')[0]
        documents = Help.objects.all()
        if form.is_valid():
            obj = form.save(commit = False)
            obj.save()
            researcher = form.cleaned_data['researcher']
            study = form.cleaned_data['study']
            document = form.cleaned_data['document']


  else:
      form = AboutHelp()
      posts = Help.objects.filter().order_by('-date')[0]  
      documents = Help.objects.all()
      return render(request, 'about_experiment.html', {'posts': posts})

  return render(request, 'about_experiment.html', {'posts': posts})
```

Source page

```
<form action="{% url 'lazer.views.about_experiment' exp.link_name %}" method="POST" name="form" enctype="multipart/form-data"> 
  {% csrf_token %}
      <label>Researcher Name(s):
        <input type="text" name="researcher"><br>
      <lable>Study Summary
        <textarea rows="10" cols="50" placeholder="Start typing..." maxlength="500" class="form-control" name="study"></textarea>
      <br>
      <label>Upload your IRB approval letter: 
        <input type ="file" id="irb-file" class="file_input" name="document"></label>
      <br>
      <input type = "submit" value="Submit" class="btn btn-primary" />
  </form>
```

destination page

```
<div class="tab-pane" id="irb">
          <h4> List of file(s) uploaded:</h4>


        <!--File upload-->
          {% if documents %}
              <ul>
              {% for file in documents %}
                  <li><a href="{{ file.document.url }}"> {{ file.document.name }} </a></li>
              {% endfor %}
              </ul>
          {% else %}
              <p>No such documents available.</p>
          {% endif %}
        <!--File upload ends-->
          </div>

          {% if high_scores %}
          {% for hs in high_scores %}
          <div class="tab-pane" id="{{ hs.link_name }}">
            {% high_score request exp.link_name hs.link_name %}
          </div>
          {% endfor %}
          {% endif %}
```

Comment: What do you expect to happen when you refresh the page? If you haven't specified a response, then that is the behavior in certain browser. Consider using `HttpResponseRedirect` to redirect users to another view, or to current view. This way, your refresh issue should be fixed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @almost a beginner pointed out, you should be redirecting to some other view, if your form is submitted successfully. If not, (in your case), when the page reloads, the code for `POST` request is executed again. ie, your form is submitted again. I could suggest some changes in your view,

```
def about_experiment(request, ex_link_name):
    exp = get_object_or_404(Experiment,link_name = ex_link_name)
    high_scores = ScoreItem.objects.filter(experiment=exp,active=True)
    context = {
      'request': request,
      'exp':exp,
      'high_scores': high_scores,
      'awards':AwardItem.objects.filter(experiment=exp,visible=True),
      'posts':Help.objects.filter().order_by('-date')[0],
      'documents':Help.objects.all()
    }

    if exp.about_file:
        context['about_file'] = settings.EXPERIMENT_DIRS+exp.about_file.get_include_path()

    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = AboutHelp(request.POST, request.FILES)

        if form.is_valid():
            obj = form.save(commit = False)
            obj.save()
            return redirect(reverse('lazer.views.about_experiment', kwargs={ 'ex_link_name':obj.link_name }))
    else:
        form = AboutHelp()

    return render(request, 'about_experiment.html', context)
```

Here, I merely assumed your `obj` has a field `link_name`. You may need to change that according to your models.

Comment: How do i redirect to my current view only? basically i want to redirect to the same page for the same experiment.
/about/exp_name

Comment: Then don't reload the page. When you reload the page in your browser, does a pop up window appear with two options `continue` and `cancel`??

Comment: I mean, when you reload the page, after submitting the form. Check that.

Comment: Yes there is nothing coming up. The HttpResponseRedirect is working well just that i cant figure out how to redirect to a particular URL with particular experiment name

Comment: To display this page, Firefox must send information that will repeat any action (such as a search or order confirmation) that was performed earlier.
with resend and cancel options

Comment: " **repeat any action** " means your submitting the form is repeated when you reload the page. Could you show me your `urls.py`?? Maybe I could help you with redirecting.

Comment: Its a big file but i have one that should work
url(r'^about/(?P<ex_link_name>\w+)', lazer.views.about_experiment, name='lazer.views.about_experiment'),

Comment: Do you want to redirect to this url after form submission??

Comment: I have edited my answer. Also, I assume your form handles with `Experiment` object and it has a field `link_name` which is the argument taken by the above said url. Hope you got the idea and make the changes accordingly if necessary.

Comment: it worked when i used return HttpResponseRedirect('/about/%s/' %ex_link_name)
Thanks for your help though

Comment: Or you could just do that. Appreciate the support.